# call the same name functions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have 2 file js in my asp website named

```
1-jquery.datepick.js

2-jquery.hijridatepick.js
```

these file have the same name functions but second one apear popup hijricalender i call it by

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('[id$=TextBox1]').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
       });
  </script>
```

for `textbox2` i wanna 2 use datepick function from first file how icall it cause i refrenced the first file as

```
 $('[id$=TextBox2]').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

but this call again the function of second file 
???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second file is overwriting the first. You must change the name of one of the functions to avoid the collision.

You'll find something like this in the files:

```
jQuery.fn.datepick = function() {
    // etc.
};
```

This is where the jQuery plugin method is created. Just change `datepick` in one or both files to something different and unique.

Comment: i searched for  jQuery.fn.datepick but i found fn.datepick what about it

Comment: Like I said, it will be something like `jQuery.fn.datepick`. Without seeing the actual files, it's hard to tell with certainty if `fn.datepick` is the right piece of code, but it probably is. Just make a back up of your files before you edit them, just in case.

Comment: but i changed  fn.datepick to fn.datepickm but not working yet but thank u 4 ur time

Answer (score 1):

As noted in FishBasketGordo's answer, the second function to load will overwrite the first, and changing the name of one will fix this, however there is a deeper problem that needs to be addressed.

The reason this happens is that the functions are being added to the global namespace. In javascript the file that the code comes from is irrelevant. One way to avoid avoid polluting the global namespace is to wrap functions inside an object, so in your case you might have:

```
/* 1-jquery.datepick.js */
datepick = new Object;
datepick.datepick = function() {
    /* function definition here */
    alert('first file function');
};

/* 2-jquery.hijridatepick.js */
hijridatepick = new Object;
hijridatepick.datepick = function() {
    /* function definition here */
    alert('second file function');
};
```

These functions can then be accessed using:

```
datepick.datepick();
/* alerts 'first file function' */

hijridatepick.datepick();
/* alerts 'second file function' */
```

Comment: sorry but i thinked that it worked but no so the first code u mean i write it in js files or edit somthing in it if i add it i will but where exactly and thank u.

Comment: @David Mason - These are good points, but remember, the two files are jQuery plugins, so they aren't polluting the global namespace. They're polluting the jQuery namespace. By separating the two functions into separate objects, you would be losing a lot of the power behind the jQuery plugin mechanism, which is a hefty tradeoff.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo - that's a good point. I guess in this case one or the other of the plugins should use a different name to prevent this type of collision in future, unless they've used the same name on purpose to allow substitution of the two.

Comment: @ahmed - if my answer or FishBasketGordo's has not answered your question, perhaps you could update your question to clarify the area we've missed, or provide more detail in your comments.